# search array value in another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, arraylist

Search array value in another array and take answer as another array. Could any body tell me to get answer which functionality should be best in php.

**First Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => answer choice 1
    [1] => answer choice 5
    [2] => answer choice 4
)
```

**Second array**

```
Array
(
    [65] => answer choice 1
    [66] => answer choice 2
    [67] => answer choice 3
    [68] => answer choice 4
    [69] => answer choice 5
)
```

**Expecting answer**

```
$result = array("65", "68", "69");
```

which method should be best to get answer ?

Comment: This looks like PHP. Why is `javascript` tagged?

Comment: You have to use `array_intersect`

Comment: @Some Guy just removed, thanks for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) with `array_keys`.

Assuming `$array1` is the 1st array and `$array2` - the 2nd, the code should look like this:

```
$result = array_keys(array_intersect($array2, $array1));
```